# howto Serialize a Nested collection using JsonWriter in C#

Tags: c#, json, excel, serialization

I need to produce the same output I produce in XML using JSON

For some tabular data that is in an Excel Worksheet, data is in the format:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
AAA      bbb     ccc
XXX      YYY     ZZZ
kkk      jjj     nnn
```

I need to write the Json file Using the Json Writer because I can't create a class to produce the data, but I have then to use the created JSON deserializing it as a class in a different application.
To be able to deserialize the class in the consumer application I need to have a class  we can name it MyClass containing a collection of Items, each Item representing a Row, the headers, Column1, Column2, Column3 are the names of the properties.

I've been able to produce this:

```
{
  "Item": {
    "Column1": "AAA",
    "Column2": "BBB",
    "Column3": "CCC",
  },
  "Item": {
    "Column1": "XXX",
    "Column2": "YYY",
    "Column3": "ZZZ",
  },
 }
```

Unfortunately this is not an object containing a collection of Item so It does not deserialize.

This is the code I use for the manual serialization from the excel file, what I was not able to find is how to script the start and end of the collection:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
JsonWriter jsonWriter = null;
jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);


jsonWriter.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
int countAwait = 0;
// Here I miss what to write to open the collection
for (int row = firstRow; row <= end.Row; row++)
{
    count++;
    countAwait++;
    if (countAwait >= 10)
    {
        ResultText = "Reading record " + count;
        countAwait = 0;
    }
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(RowElement);
    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
    for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
    {
        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(fieldNames[col]);
        jsonWriter.WriteValue(GetCellStringValue(ws, row, col));

    }
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
}
// Here I need to write the closing of the collection

jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
jsonWriter.Close();
```

Edited to add how the Json Serializer serializes a sample of my destination class:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Column1": "XXX",
      "Column2": "YYY",
      "Column3": "ZZZ",
    },
    {
      "Column1": "AAA",
      "Column2": "BBB",
      "Column3": "CCC",
    }
  ]
}
```

The class is MyClass and Contains a collection Items of Classes of type Item.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of the JSON you want to create, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write the property name `"Items"` only once, then for its value use [`JsonWriter.WriteStartArray()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteStartArray.htm) and [`JsonWriter.WriteEndArray()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteEndArray.htm) to start and end a JSON array, then write each row as an object nested in the array:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    var countAwait = 0;

    jsonWriter.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject(); // Write the opening of the root object
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(RowElement); // Write the "Items" property name
    jsonWriter.WriteStartArray(); // Write the opening of the "Items" array

    for (int row = firstRow; row <= end.Row; row++)
    {
        count++;
        countAwait++;
        if (countAwait >= 10)
        {
            ResultText = "Reading record " + count;
            countAwait = 0;
        }
        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject(); // Write the beginning of an entry in the "Items" array
        for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
        {
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(fieldNames[col]);
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(GetCellStringValue(ws, row, col));

        }
        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject(); // Write the ending of an entry in the "Items" array
    }

    jsonWriter.WriteEndArray(); // Write the closing of the "Items" array.
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject(); // Write the closing of the root object
    // No need to close explicitly when inside a using statement
}
```

(Here I am assuming that `RowElement` corresponds to the `"Items"` string.)

Comment: Thanks that was it.