# How to construct JSON key name dynamically based on number of model in C#?

Tags: c#, json, collections

For example:

```
{
   "Books": [
       {
           "Name-1":"The Alchemist",
           "Type-1":"Fiction"
       },
       {
           "Name-2":"Silent Spring",
           "Type-2":"Non-Fiction"
       },
       {
           "Name-3":"1984",
           "Type-3":"Fiction"
       }
   ]
}
```

I have Books model defined with properties "Name" and "Type". How do I create the JSON as above from Books collection?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? The reason why this isn't easy to do in the libraries we already have for JSON handling is that this requirement is *very* strange, it would make it hard for an app consuming this JSON to get the mapping right without dynamic mapping to handle this.

Comment: I understand the concern. But the API will be consumed this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map Books to Dictionary<string, string> and serialize them.
Something like:

```cs
    serializer.Serialize(new { Books = books.Select((x, i) => 
        new Dictionary<string, string> { 
            { $"{nameof(x.Name}-{i+1}", x.Name }, 
            { $"{nameof(x.Type}-{i+1}", x.Type }
        }});

However, it looks very WIERD to have such a Json (I mean with indexes as property names of objects in same array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate json via JsonTextWriter

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WritePropertyName("Books");

            writer.WriteStartArray();

            //your for


            writer.WriteEndArray();

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
```

[similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417556/howto-serialize-data-consist-an-array-using-jsonwriter-in-c-sharp)